# CSS Snap Scrolling horizontal not working

Tags: html, css

From the materials I've read online, the following code should produce a horizontal snap scroll on the page:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.seq {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;

  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
   <div class="seq">
       <div class="content" style="background: yellow;"></div>
       <div class="content" style="background: red;"></div>
       <div class="content" style="background: blue;"></div>
   </div>
</section>
```

But, from what I've been testing, I had no success on having my horizontal scroll. What am I missing it? I've already tried to set the content size to a hard-coded value too.

Comment: Might be that you've set the width incorrectly.

Comment: What would be the right way? :v

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to happen as you have set the parent to flex so in essence there is no scrolling, everything fits.

Comment: its a horizontal snap scroll. If u seach on google, plenty of examples are like that. It's weird, i know, but somehow they work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've realized what I was missing it. On the content class, put:

```
flex: none;
```

since the class is not meant to flex itself to fit, but just be the height and width that it needs to be.